# A uniformly continuous function between totally bounded uniform spaces

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces, uniform-continuity

Let $X$ and $Y$ is a uniform spaces. Let $f$ is a uniformly continuous surjective function $X\rightarrow Y$.

Conjecture: If $X$ is totally bounded then $Y$ is also totally bounded.

Comment: I added additional condition that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: What does total boundedness mean for uniform spaces?

Comment: @CameronBuie: There are two equivalent definitions of total boundness for uniform spaces: 1. For every entourage $E$ there exists a finite cover $S$ of the space such that $\forall A\in S:A\times A\subseteq E$. 2. For every entourage $E$ there exists a finite set $B$ such that $E[B]$ is the entire space.

Comment: My experience with uniform spaces is limited. I'll have to think on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the conjecture is well known and can be proved straightforwardly. Let $f:(X,{\cal E})\to (Y,\cal F)$ be a surjective uniformly continuous map between uniform spaces and the space $(X,\cal E)$ is totally bounded. Let $F\in\cal F$ be an arbitrary entourage. Since the map $f$ is uniformly continuous, there exists an entourage $E\in\cal E$ such that $E\subset (f\times f)^{-1}(F)$. Since the space $(X,\cal E)$ is totally bounded, there exists a finite subset $A$ of $X$ such that $E[A]=X$. We claim that $F[f(A)]=Y$. Indeed, let $y\in Y$ be an arbitrary point. Since the map $f$ is surjective, there exists a point $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. Since $E[A]=X$, there exists a point $a\in A$ such that $(a,x)\in E$.  Since $E\subset (f\times f)^{-1}(F)$, we see that $(f(a),y)=(f(a),f(x))\in F$. Therefore $y\in F[f(A)]$.