# Is there an unbounded uniformly continuous function with a bounded domain?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, uniform-continuity

I tried to solve it by cases: domain is a set of numbers; domain is an interval,;domain is a union of numbers and some intervals.

For the first case, I thought about arctanh is unbounded but its domain is bounded. To make it uniformly continuous, I can let Z be the domain.

For the second case, I think there does not exist a function like this.

For the third case, I am not sure if there exists a function satisfying all these conditions..

Did I think anything wrong for this question? or Could you give some idea or hint about that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If $f$ is uniformly continuous, and its domain $D$ is [totally bounded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space), then [$f$ must be a bounded function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407622/a-uniformly-continuous-function-between-totally-bounded-uniform-spaces). So, to find the necessary counterexample, you need to be a little trickier...

Here is a counterexample:
Consider 
$$
\begin{align}
f:(\mathbb R,d) &\to(\mathbb R,|\cdot|)\\
x &\mapsto x
\end{align}
$$
Where $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the metric defined by
$$
d(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
|x-y| & |x - y|<1\\
1 & |x-y|\geq 1
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is uniformly continuous, its domain is bounded (but not totally bounded), and its image is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

The image of a totally bounded subset under a uniformly continuous function is totally bounded. However, the image of a bounded subset of an arbitrary metric space under a uniformly continuous function need not be bounded: as a counterexample, consider the identity function from the integers endowed with the discrete metric to the integers endowed with the usual Euclidean metric.