# Is $\sqrt{x}$ uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is $\sqrt{x}$ uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$?

And can anybody give me a function that is uniformly continuous on some interval but $f^2$ is not?

Comment: Huh... I always thought $\sqrt 2\notin (0,1)$...

Comment: @abiessu OP likely means $f(x) \equiv \sqrt{2}$ and that would be defined for all real $x$, including $x \in (0,1)$...

Comment: These questions are not related enough; they should probably be asked in two separate posts.

Comment: But $f(x) = x$ should work.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x$ is uniformly continuous but $f^2(x)=x^2$ is not.

Comment: sorry guys stupid typo should ve been square root of x

Comment: Oops, yes, only works over $\mathbb{R}$.  Over any finite interval, if $f$ is uniformly continuous, then $f^2$ is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{2}$ is a constant, not a function. If you mean $f(x) = \sqrt{2}$ for all values of $x$, it would be uniformly continuous.

Comment: sorry should ve been square root of x

Answer (score 1):

Weierstrass theorem. Every continuous function is uniformly continuous over any compact set. So constant functions are continuous then they are uniformly over any compact , particularly over 0,1

EDIT1: Particularly over [0,1] and therefore over any subset of [0,1], for example (0,1).

EDIT2: I am sorry to credit this theorem to Weierstrass.

Comment: I have heard this called Heine-Cantor, and I have heard it unnamed (usually mentioned shortly after proving Heine-Borel, since there is a very elegant proof using topological compactness). I have never heard it attributed to Weierstrass. Also, a function can be continuous on $(0,1)$ but not extensible to $[0,1]$, in which case Heine-Cantor is not applicable. For instance $f(x)=\tan(\pi x - \pi/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

JVV has given an example that fails on $\Bbb R$.

But on $(0,1)$ (or any bounded interval), which is [totally bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space), a uniformly continuous function $f$ can be extended to a continuous function $\tilde f$ on $[0,1]$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761340/uniformly-continuous-on-a-bounded-set)). In particular, $\tilde f$ is continuous, and so is $\tilde f^2$. And a continuous function on a compact is uniformly continuous ([Heine-Cantor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem)), hence $\tilde f^2$ is uniformy continuous, and so is $f^2$, on $(0,1)$.