# A uniformly continuous on the unit sphere of $c_0$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $S_{c_0}= \{ x\in c_0 \;: \Vert x \Vert =\;1\; \}$, where $c_0$ is the space of all sequences converging to zero and 
$$f: S_{c_0} \rightarrow \mathbb R$$
is a uniformly continuous function. Prove that $f$ is  bounded.

I thought that if I could show $S_{c_0}$ is a compact set then by using the continuity of $f$, I would result in the requested point, but I feel like I'm missing something.

Could anyone please help or give some hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @John Ma Well.....it couldn't be that simple! thank you for pointing it out.. Nevertheless could you help me with this ?

Comment: What is the norm on $C_0$?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri This is a good question. This exercise(among with other exersices) was given to us by our professor for Easter holidays at the end of the class so we couldn't make questions over the homework. I don't know what norm this is  but I assume that is the ${\Vert x \Vert}_\infty $ , the norm of $l_\infty$ space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use that $f$ is uniform continuous. By definition, it means that: For all $\epsilon >0$, there is $\delta >0$ so that $|f(y) - f(x)| <\epsilon$ whenever $\| x- y\| <\delta$. Now pick $\epsilon =1$ and $\delta_1$ be the corresponding $\delta$ in the statement.

Let $x\in S_{c_0}$. Let 
$$ e_1 = (1, 0, 0, \cdots ) \in S_{c_0}.$$
We will find $x = x_0, \cdots, x_N=e_1$, where $x_i \in S_{c_0}$ so that $\|x_i - x_{i-1}\| <\delta_1$ and $N$ is independent of $x$. Then
$$\begin{split}
|f(x)| &= | f(x) - f(e_1) + f(e_1)| \\ 
&= |f(x_0) - f(x_N) + f(e_1)|\\
&\le |f(x_0) - f(x_N)| + |f(e_1)| \\
&\le  |f(x_0) - f(x_{1})| + |f(x_{1}) - f(x_{2})| + \cdots + |f(x_{N-1}) - f(x_N)| + |f(e_1)| \\
&\le N + |f(e_1)|
\end{split}$$

Since $N + |f(e_1)|$ is independent of $x$, we have that $f$ is bounded.

To find $x_1, \cdots x_N$ first we write $x = (x^1, x^2, \cdots x^n, \cdots )$ and let

$$\begin{split} x_1 &= x + \frac{1-x^1}{N_1} e_1,\\
 x_2 &= x+\frac{2(1-x^1)}{N_1} e_1, \cdots , \\
x_{N_1} &= x+ \frac{N_1(1-x^1)}{N_1}e_1 = x+ (1-x^1)e_1. 
\end{split}$$

where $N_1$ is fixed so that $\frac{2}{N_1}<\delta_1$. Note that 
$$x_{N_1} = (1, x^2, x^3, \cdots ).$$
Next we connect $x_{N_1}$ to $e_1$. Let

$$\begin{split}
x_{N_1 +1} &= (1,  \frac{N_1-1}{N_1} x^2, \frac{N_1 -1}{N_1} x^3 , \cdots ) \\
x_{N_1 +2} &= (1,  \frac{N_1-2}{N_1} x^2, \frac{N_1 -2}{N_1} x^3 , \cdots ) \\
&\cdots \\
x_{2N_1-1} &= (1,  \frac{1}{N_1} x^2, \frac{1}{N_1} x^3 , \cdots ) \\
x_{2N_1} &= (1, 0, 0, \cdots ) = e_1.
\end{split}$$

Thus we have found the sequence $x_1, \cdots x_N$ with $N = 2N_1$.

(As spotted in the comment, some extra works has to be done when $x^1 = -1$. In this case one might connect it to $-e_1$, and the bound would be 
$$N + \max\{ |f(e_1)|, |f(-e_1)|\}$$
instead)

Comment: With a couple of caveats: there's a typo on the formula for $x_2$, and more annoyingly, the method doesn't always work if $x^1 = -1$ (you need additional steps).

Comment: @D.Thomine : Thanks and edited.

Comment: @JohnMa This is the kind of answer I hoped for!! You explained this in detail, but I still have some questions. First , I understand why $\Vert x \Vert=1$ since $ x\in S_{C_0}$, but why is $\Vert x^1 \Vert=1$? (it may be a very silly question to make but I don't get it In addition, could you expain how do we result in $. x_{N_1\;+1}?$ (What do you mean by connecting $x_{N_1}\;to\;e_1$ ?) However, thank you very much for your time and your answer!! You helped me a lot!

Comment: Do you mean $\|x_1\|$ instead of $\|x^1\|$? $x^1$ is a number. @kaithkolesidou

Comment: @John Ma In the above construction, you say $N_1$ is fixed, so that $\frac{2}{N_1}<\delta_1$ . This is because you want $x_1, \cdots x_N$ satisfy $\|x_i - x_{i-1}\| <\delta_1$, am I right? So, for example $\|x_2 - x_1\| <\frac{\|1 - x^1\|}{N_1} < \frac{2}{N_1}$ which implies that $\|x^1\| \le 1$ (from the triangle inequality ) . Why is this true? What am I missing? I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: Oh, since $\|x\|$ is the sup norm, so $1=\|x\| = \sup\{ |x^i|\}$ and that implies $|x^i|\le 1$. @kaithkolesidou

Comment: @JohnMa yyyyyyyesss!!! you're right! I missed that! Thank you very very much for your time! You 've been very helpful!!

Comment: @JohnMa May I ask you a last question about the answer? Why does the method not work if $ x^1\;=\;-1$ ? Even if $ x^1\;=\;-1$  ,then $x_{N_1} = (1, x^2, x^3, \cdots )$, so where exactly is the problem?

Comment: If $x^1  =-1$, then the $x_1$ constructed above might not be in $S_{c_0}$ (for example, if $x = (-1, 0,0,0,\cdots)$, then $x_1 = (-1 + \frac{2}{N_1} , 0,0,0,\cdots) \notin S_{c_0}$). @kaithkolesidou

Answer (score 0):

The unit sphere of $c_0$ is certainly not compact as the set $\{e_n\colon n\in \mathbb{N}\}\subset S_{c_0}$ is closed and discrete. (The unit sphere of a normed space is compact if and only if the space is finite-dimensional.)

However, you may adapt [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1497040/17929) to see that that the unit ball as well as the unit spehre of a normed space has the property that each uniformly continuous function on it is bounded.

Comment: @ Tomek Kania Well, I'm a little "new" to functional analysis , that's why I thought so careless. My mistake. Thank you for pointing out and explained this with an example. I just saw the proof you mentioned and it would also work! :)

Comment: The proof works for unit ball, but I guess more has to be done for the sphere.

Comment: @JohnMa, the proof works in every metric space whose every pair of points can be joined by a curve of some finite length $\leqslant L$, where $L$ is dependent only on the space.